# Finding prime numbers

Tags: primes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which is the fastest algorithm to find prime numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453793/which-is-the-fastest-algorithm-to-find-prime-numbers)

What is the fastest way to check if a number is prime( large numbers). I have tried the standard method i.e running a loop till root(n) or (n/2) and checking if anything divides it. Also i have tried the sieve method. Is there anything better to implement in c++?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453793/which-is-the-fastest-algorithm-to-find-prime-numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test has all you need.

Answer (score 1):

One tip is that you can ignore any even numbers (so add 2 at a time when either looking for factors or checking values).