# faster way of computing large numbers java

Tags: java, performance, primes, biginteger

I was looking at the wikipedia page on [primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number) and of course, I came across the largest known prime which is `2^43,112,609 − 1`. This number is exceptionally large. So for fun, I decided to put this into `BigInteger`. To calculate this, it would take a very long time (I gave up after a while).

Is there any faster of computing a very large number like this? Or is `BigInteger` and a better computer the only way? Any reduction of time would be great.

*Note that my question has nothing to do with finding prime numbers. I'm asking if there is a better way to compute the number `2^43,112,609 − 1`.

Comment: how about using logarithm tables? so something like `Math.exp(n * Math.log(2)) -1`. that should be faster.

Comment: please provide examples, I am not aware of logarithm tables but I will "google it".

Comment: can that be done on BigInteger? `Math.exp`?

Comment: you can consider the ideas in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453793/which-is-the-fastest-algorithm-to-find-prime-numbers

Comment: nope, but didnt you put it in BigInteger as an attempt to solve the problem? anyways, you could still get integer from bigint and use that with Math functions.

Comment: I didn't what you just recommended into the BIgInteger (yet).

Comment: @prusswan I am not interested in finding the largest prime, but just computing that specific one.

Comment: so are you referring to a primality test of a particular number?

Comment: @prusswan no, I am just interesting in computing that large number. I know I can use BigInteger, I am looking for a more efficent way to reduce time.

Comment: I've clarified your question. Feel free to revert it if you don't like my changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with `BigInteger` is that it isn't meant for such large numbers. Last time I checked, it was still using ***quadratic run-time algorithms*** for both its multiplication and it's base conversion.

So the reason why computing `2^43,112,609 − 1` takes so long is that it's just huge - and you're trying to put that through a quadratic run-time algorithm.

Unfortunately, if you want something faster you will need to use a better bignum library. In C/C++ you have [GMP](http://gmplib.org/). There are Java wrappers for it if you google around.

---

*Note that computing `2^43,112,609 − 1` itself is fast since you can do it with just a shift. The slow part is printing out as a string in base 10. Java still uses an `O(n^2)` algorithm for this conversion.

Efficient programs will be able do this conversion in roughly `O(n * log(n)^2)` time - which will be under a minute using the latest version of GMP on most up-to-date machines today.

Answer (score 1):

As noted above by Mysticial, BigInteger isn't really meant to handle such large numbers. Here's a link to a Java wrapper of GMP. I haven't used it, but I've heard a few positive things, so it may be worth giving it a try:

[Java wrapper for GMP](https://bitbucket.org/dfdeshom/gmp-java/overview)

Answer (score 0):

`BigInteger` has a `pow` method, which is likely the best for handling large numbers. Check the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) for more.

Also, as explained in the linked question @prusswan brought up, many of those answers also show primegen algorithms which would help.

Comment: Actually, In case of OP's case, using a `shiftLeft` will be more efficient than `pow`, since it's `2`