# Program that checks if given number is prime number

Tags: java, primes

Hello i got little program here that checks if given number is prime number, but i dont understand some part in for loop and i need your help.
here is the code:

```
public class PrimeNumber
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        int number;
        boolean prime;
        /*
            *is a natural number greater than 1 that has no positive divisors other 
            *than 1 and itself.
            * such as: 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 
            * 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, and so on.
            */
        number =23;

        if(number<2)  
            prime=false; 
        else
            prime=true; 
        for(int i=2; i <=number/2; i++) 
        {
            if ((number%i) ==0) 
            { 
                prime =false; 
                break;
            }
        }
        if(prime) System.out.println("It is prime number");
        else System.out.println("it is not prime number");
    }
}
```

I understand that first if function checks if given numbers is higher than 2 if it is not
prime will be false, if it will prime will be true.
Then in for loop i think int is 2 because 2 is the smallest possible prime number ?
I understand <= this operator checks if i is less than or equal to number but i dont understand why we used number/2 ? and why we had to check if there is rest between these two numbers in last if function ?

Comment: The code is poorly written so I can't tell you why you did those things rather than use a much more efficient and widely available solution.  If you want to understand your code, I suggest you try using a debugger or changing it and see what difference it makes.

Comment: When you say `we` it begs the question; why don't you ask the person who wrote it why they did what they did?

Comment: This code is from one book i bought.

Comment: Look up the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

Comment: Yeah, there might be better solution for this but i dont know, i am just beginner and this is the first time i write program for prime numbers.

Comment: @Milan IMHO you should throw away that book. When an error like that is done on a such algorithm, I'm afraid about the more important thing that could not be taken care. You check first if number if the number is even and then you loop `for(int i=3; i <=sqrt(number); i=i+2)`

Answer (score 3):

The author checks only up to `n/2`, because if `2` is the smallest possible factor, then `n/2` is the largest possible <s>factor</s> divisor(?). While it is not the largest possible factor, the algorithm writer knew for sure that no factor could possibly be larger than `n/2`.

The author then uses `n % i == 0` to check if the number is divisible by any number in the range. If it is, it is definitely not a prime.

Keep in mind this is not the most efficient way of prime checking. See [Which is the fastest algorithm to find prime numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453793/which-is-the-fastest-algorithm-to-find-prime-numbers)

Comment: In fact, the largest possible divisible number is `ceil(sqrt(number))`, not `number/2`.

Comment: In fact, the largest non-trivial divisor of 26 is 13, which is larger than ceil(sqrt(26)).

Comment: @DonRoby if you're that technical, the largest factor of 26 is 26 :).

Comment: @DonRoby While true, you would eliminate 26 earlier than that, as it is divisible by 2.

Comment: It's inefficient because you only need to check factors up to `ceil(sqrt(number))` because any factor greater than that would already have been checked implicitly because it would need to be paired with one less than that.

Comment: @AustinSalonen OP is not asking for an efficient prime number function, he's asking what the posted code does and why.

Comment: Yes, you only have to check factors up to ceil(sqrt(number)).  But there are greater divisors.

Comment: @Rotem:  No doubt.  I was really just clarifying the point made by @Luiggi w/r/t the sqrt as to why typical prime number checkers stop at a certain value that isn't always `number/2`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to check that `number` does not have any divisors other than 1 and itself,
and if you checked all integers until `number/2`, then obviously, you don't need to check more numbers since `i` can not be a divisor of `number` for `i>number/2` if `number/i` is not a divisor.

with the same logic, you can make it more efficient by replacing this line:

```
 for(int i=2; i <=number/2; i++)
```

with this line:

```
for(int i=2; i <=sqrt(number); i++)
```