# Implementing a prime number counter

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, primes

For some reason, my last prime(int prime) isn't showing up at the end. Any clue ?
fyi: primeEval stands for a flag, if the loop ends && primeEval==2, the number is actually a prime number. qty stands for quantity of primes counted.

```
int main(){


long primeEval=0,prime=0,qtyprime=0;

time_t timerr=(time(NULL)+10);



   for (int i = 2; time(NULL)!=timerr; i++) {

        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {

            if((i%j)==0 && primeEval<2){

                primeEval++;

                if (i==j && primeEval==2) {
                    qtyprime++;
                    prime=i;
                    primeEval=0; // Resets for the next number 'i'

                }
            }

        }
    }

cout << "last prime found: " << prime << endl << "Ttal primes found: " << qtyprime;
}
```

Comment: you could easily improve performance by changing `j <= i` to `j <= sqrt(i)`. This would enforce more changes, but it would run faster

Comment: What do you mean it's not showing up? Like it's giving the wrong number? not printing at all?

Comment: @OlivierPoulin
The output is:
last prime found: 2
Ttal primes found: 45190040

Comment: Also, once you've found a number `y=i%j`, why continue the inner loop? finish it immediately and move on to the next number.

Comment: @shapiro.yaacov to be a prime number, must be only divided by itself and 1, primeEval gets 2 flags to indicate that's prime.

Comment: Then `j = 2` - not `j = 1`.

Comment: Why are you only checking even numbers? Shouldn't you find more prime numbers if you look at the odd numbers?

Comment: Why do you only reset primeEval when you found a prime number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New Answer:

With the change in your code you will now loop through all number.  The problem with it now is that once you find a non prime number you will never reset `primeEval` and because of that you will never capture another prime number  If you change your code to the following it will work

```
int main()
{
    long primeEval = 0, prime = 0, qtyprime = 0;
    time_t timerr = (time(NULL) + 10);

    for (int i = 2; time(NULL) != timerr; i++) {

        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {

            if ((i%j) == 0){
                primeEval++;  // incmrent factor
            }
            // if we are at the end and have 2 factors then we are prime
            if (i == j && primeEval == 2) {
                qtyprime++;
                prime = i;
                primeEval = 0; // Resets for the next number 'i'
            }
            // if we reach the end with more than 2 factors reset and go to the next number
            if (i == j && primeEval > 2) {
                primeEval = 0; // Resets for the next number 'i'
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "last prime found: " << prime << endl << "Ttal primes found: " << qtyprime;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

I would also suggest you look at [Which is the fastest algorithm to find prime numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453793/which-is-the-fastest-algorithm-to-find-prime-numbers) to find some more efficient ways to get prime numbers.

Old Answer:

In your code you have:

```
for (int i = 2; time(NULL)!=timerr; i=+2)
```

So when you start checking from primes you start with 2 which is prime.  Then you increment `i` by 2 so the next number you check is 4 which is an even number.  All even numbers are not prime except for 2.  Since you are always adding 2 you will always have an even number so the only prime number you will find is 2.

Comment: It was a old implementation(to only check odd numbers) that i forgot to correct, but its i++ instead of i+2.

Comment: @sayajeans so is it fixed?

Comment: "Then you increment i by 2 so the next number you check is 4 which is an even number": Now OP has explained it's a typo and he wanted to write `i++`, but since he wrote `+=` instead of `=+`, what he was actually doing was setting `i` to +2, every time.

Comment: Argh, damned typos! What I meant is: he wrote `=+` instead of `+=`.

Answer (score 0):

You have different issues:

```
for (int i = 2; time(NULL)!=timerr; i=+2) {
```

Here the syntax is just wrong: it must be `i+=2`, not `i=+2`, otherwise you will keep setting i to +2 and testing whether 2 is prime.

Then, as others have pointed out, why are you increasing `i` by 2? If you want to optimize the search, you should increase `j` by 2, not `i`! And j should in any case start from 2 (or, given your approach, from 1), and then you should try j = 3 and then you can increase j by 2 without the risk of skipping some important divisors.

Then, you reset `primeEval` to 0 only if you find a prime. If you test a number `i` that is not prime, primeEval stays at 2 and you'll never get into the block again.

So the final code could be:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    long primeEval=0,prime=0,qtyprime=0;

    time_t timerr=(time(NULL)+10);

    for (int i = 2; time(NULL)!=timerr; i++) {
        primeEval=0;
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            if((i%j)==0 && primeEval<2){
                primeEval++;
                if (i==j && primeEval==2) {
                    qtyprime++;
                    prime=i;
                    primeEval=0; // Resets for the next number 'i'
                }
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "last prime found: " << prime << endl << "Ttal primes found: " << qtyprime;
}
```