# an algorithm to check if the number is prime in O(1) Time

Tags: algorithm, math

is there's an algorithm that checks if a number is a prime.
without requiring checking each number that precedes it?
or at least a bit more performant than that?

and i'm not talking about the low effort ''' if num == 2 || num % 2 == 1''' (psuedocode)

Comment: From the dup question, I suspect [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/454039/238704) is most relevant.

Comment: Dup is not correct, OP want a primality test not to find a prime number. There exists a polynomial primality test: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test